# Nested looping in svelte using svelte:self

Tags: javascript, loops, recursion, svelte, sveltekit

Following is my data

```
let mainMenuLinks = [
    {
        name: 'Services',
        link: '/services',
        children: [
            {
                service1: 'Auditng & Assurance',
                icon: 'fa fa-check',
                link: '/services/audit',
                caption: 'We provide a full range of audit and assurance services to a wide range of clients',
                sublinks: [
                    { name: 'Compliance Audit', link: '/services/audit/compliance' },
                    { name: 'Financial Audit', link: '/services/audit/financial' },
                ]
            },

            {
                service2: 'Taxation',
                icon: 'fa fa-calculator',
                link: '/services/taxation',
                caption: 'We provide a full range of audit and assurance services to a wide range of clients',
                sublinks: [
                    { name: 'Corporate Tax', link: '/services/taxation/corporate' },
                    { name: 'Individual Tax', link: '/services/taxation/individual' },
                ]
            }, 
    }
];
```

My objective is to get children.service1 and children.sublinks using svelte:self. Is it possible to get it or should I opt for recursions or multiple loops?

Thank you

Edit:

The following is what I have tried. But I think it can be done better

```
<script>
    export let links;
</script>

{#each links as link}
    <h3>
    {link.name}
</h3>
{#each link.children as item, index}
<h5>
    {item[`service${index+1}`]}
</h5>

    {#each item.children as i}
        <p>
            {i.name}
</p>
    {/each}
{/each}
{/each}
```

Comment: What have you tried and what is the problem?

Comment: @H.B: I have edited the question with the solution I have tried. I used 3 each loop to get the values I wanted. But I feel that there is a better way to achieve it.